# test dependencies with the Gradle Android build system doesn't update Android Studio *.iml file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I do not understand while syncing my build.gradle with androidTestCompile dependency, it is not updating myproject.iml file.

[image]

As you can see on my build.gradle,  I have my dependency :

```
dependencies {

androidTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0' 
}
```

I use flavors

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = 'com.myapp.pro'
        testApplicationId 'com.myapp.pro.test'
    }
    free {
        applicationId = 'com.myapp.free'
        testApplicationId 'com.myapp.free.test'
    }
}
```

But on iml file, I was expecting an entry like this but I have nothing :

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="assertj-core-1.7" level="project" />
```

I use android studio 1.0 RC 2 and the recent plugin com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2

Edit :

if I have remove the flavors block from my build.gradle, the iml is correctly generated by Android Studio.

Comment: Got the same problem, opened a bug for android studio: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=83077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the issue,I have to choose the correct variant from Android Studio and the iml file will be updated.

[image: On the bottom left, you see "Build Variants" button, click on it, a new panel will appear and you will able to choose your variant]

On the bottom left, you see "Build Variants" button, click on it, a new panel will appear and you will able to choose your variant

Comment: Where exactly did you choose the variant in Android Studio? I have the same problem as you described above.